# query about switch function in java

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please choose the operator");
System.out.println("1-->+ \n2-->- \n3-->* \n4-->/");
int z = input.nextInt();

switch (z) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("your result is" + (x + y));
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("your result is" + (x - y));
        break;

    case 3:
        System.out.println("your result is" + (x * y));
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("your result is" + (x / y));
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("choose the option from listed above");
        break;
}
```

above code is for calculator in switch...
query is :
how can i call the switch function again in default case ?

Comment: Switch is a statement and not a function. What you call a function, in Java is called a method. If you want repetition you will need to include all your code in a while loop.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't execute the `switch` statement again because that does not solve the problem. `z`'s value does not change, so it will always go to the default branch no matter how many times you re-execute the `switch`.

I suggest to put the whole thing in a loop and break out of the loop for cases 1-4.

```
loop:
while (true) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please choose the operator");
    System.out.println("1-->+ \n2-->- \n3-->* \n4-->/");
    int z=input.nextInt();

    switch(z)
    {
    case 1 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x+ y));
        break loop;
    case 2 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x- y));
        break loop;

    case 3 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x* y));
        break loop;
    case 4 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x/ y));
        break loop;  
    default :
        System.out.println("choose the option from listed above");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote `break loop` instead of `break`. `break` will just break out of the switch statement. This is why I added a label `loop:` before the loop starts, so that I can break out of the loop, instead of the `switch`, later.

**Some corrections of your terminology**

In Java, there are technically no functions. Functions must be outside of a class. There are only "methods" in Java. They look like this:

```
public static void someMethod(int somePar) { }
```

`switch` is neither a function nor a method, so you can't "call" it. `switch` is a control structure that is "executed" or "run".

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
public void promptUser(){

  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean validOption = false;

  while(!validOption){
    validOption = true;

    System.out.println("please choose the operator");
    System.out.println("1-->+ \n2-->- \n3-->* \n4-->/");
    int z=input.nextInt();

    switch(z){
      case 1 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x+ y));
        break;
      case 2 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x- y));
        break;
      case 3 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x* y));
        break;
      case 4 :
        System.out.println("your result is"+(x/ y));
        break;  
      default :
        System.out.println("choose the option from listed above");
        validOption = false;
        break;
    }

 }

}
```

I prefer using a loop so you won't be stacking a lot of calls to the same method over and over, thus you can avoid `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your code is in a function called `calculate()`

There are a few ways you could do this.

**Recursively:**

Just call the function again in the switch.

```
default :
    System.out.println("choose the option from listed above");
    calculate();
    return;
```

**Return a value and loop:**

Change the function so it returns a value. For example, return true if is does anything but default, and false if it hits default. Then, in the logic that calls calculate(), put it in some sort of loop.

```
bool doLoop = true;
while (doLoop)
{
    doLoop = !calculate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it inside a loop, for example a do ... while loop, and you may capture a key as ending condition.

```
do {
    // your code here
} while(ending_condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
{   
   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("please choose the operator");
   System.out.println("1-->+ \n2-->- \n3-->* \n4-->/ \n5-->Exit");
   int z=input.nextInt();

   switch(z)
   {
    case 1 :
    System.out.println("your result is"+(x+ y));
    break;
    case 2 :
    System.out.println("your result is"+(x- y));
    break;

    case 3 :
    System.out.println("your result is"+(x* y));
    break;
    case 4 :
    System.out.println("your result is"+(x/ y));
    break;
    case 5 :
    System.exit(0);
    default :
    System.out.println("choose the option from listed above");
    break;
    }
}
```